# roscpp roslaunch get arguments

Tags: roslaunch, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launcher with some arguments, so I expect to launch it like this

```
roslaunch my_package my_launcher.launch my_argument:=some_value
```

Is there a way to get the value of "my_argument" ("some_value" as a string or number if it's a number) from the node code?

I want to do something like this:

```
std::string my_value = ros::launch::?????::get_arg("my_argument");
```

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181694/roscpp-roslaunch-get-arguments/) by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-01**:
You can get this argument in the launch file and send it over to the node you are starting. From the node you will get it as the args[] from (int argn, char *args[]).

Doing it directly isn't possible I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/29461/roslaunch-with-arguments/

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1